# Search for specific key in nested dictionary?

Tags: python

I have 2 barcode scanners that i need to check against a nested dictionary.

First i need to find the key that corresponds with the matching 'Outer' barcode from scanner1.

Than i need to run the key and find the corresponding 'Inner' barcode, then compare the result to scanner2 to see if they match. This checks we have the correct items in a carton.

I have tried a few examples but they don't seem to work.

When i run this i only get None returned.

This is part of my dictionary that i have to search.

```
    barcodes = {1: {'Outer': '10000261344131', 'Inner': '26214092', 'Lane': '3', 'Group': '1'},
               2: {'Outer': '10000261343905', 'Inner': '26134390', 'Lane': '3', 'Group': '1'},
               3: {'Outer': '10000261343769', 'Inner': '26134376', 'Lane': '1', 'Group': '1'},
               4: {'Outer': '14088700046026', 'Inner': '4088700046029', 'Lane': '0', 'Group': '0'},
               5: {'Outer': '19100010090011', 'Inner': '9100010090011', 'Lane': '1', 'Group': '0'},
               6: {'Outer': '19300601775283', 'Inner': '9300601775286', 'Lane': '1', 'Group': '0'},
               7: {'Outer': '19300633223844', 'Inner': '9300633223847', 'Lane': '1', 'Group': '0'}}

    scanner1 = '19300633223844'
    scanner2 = '9300633223847'

    def search(values, searchFor):
            for k in values:
                for v in values[k]:
                    if searchFor in v:
                        return k
            return None

        #Checking if string 'Mary' exists in dictionary value
        groupfind = search(barcodes, str(scanner1))
```

Comment: You should reorganize your data structure to have a flat dictionary with the scan results as keys. One you will have more items this will speed up finding the right item a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> First i need to find the key that corresponds with the matching
>   'Outer' barcode from scanner1.

```
matches = [k for k, v in barcodes.items() if v["Outer"] == scanner1]
```

> Than i need to run the key and find the corresponding 'Inner' barcode,
>   then compare the result to scanner2 to see if they match. This checks
>   we have the correct items in a carton.

```
if matches:
    key = matches[0]  # Assumes only 1 match can be found in the first step.
    if barcodes[key]["Inner"] == scanner2:
        print("Inner matches scanner2")
    else:
        print("Inner doesn't match scanner2"]
```

Comment: I have tried this returns empty match. If i substitute scanner1 for '10000261343905' i get 2 returned. I have tried to format to string but nothing seems to work.